# Fotorama jquery - add links to external pages on slides

Tags: jquery, fotorama

I've integrated a fotorama's slideshow with thumbs. I love this plugin, but in this case, the syntax is :

```
<div class="fotorama"
data-nav="thumbs">
<a href="1.jpg"><img src="1_thumb.jpg"></a>
(...)
```

The  is used to display the large images, so I can't add a link to an external page.

I can't write this!! :

Has somebody a solution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use [HTML technique](http://fotorama.io/customize/html/) to add transparent links over frames:

```
<div class="fotorama">
  <div data-img="1.jpg"><a href="http://google.com/"></a></div>
  <div data-img="2.jpg"><a href="http://apple.com/"></a></div>
</div>
```

Stretch links with CSS:

```
.fotorama__html div,
.fotorama__html a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  /* Transparent links are not clickable in IE,
     but non-existent background fixes this.
    (Put an empty 1×1 image here to avoid
     errors in console.) */
  background: url(_.gif);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/gzQwy/.

Comment: But after I applied $('.fotorama').fotorama(), the build in fotorama codes prevents me from clicking of the "inside" links.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the above suggestion and found a problem on Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.153 m). The external link only  worked intermittently. So I browsed around for solution and found a fix:

Goto chrome://flags/ and enabled the followings:

Fixed position elements create stacking contexts. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Enabling this option makes all fixed position elements create new CSS stacking contexts. #fixed-position-creates-stacking-context

AND

Compositing for fixed position elements. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Enabling this option will make fixed position elements have their own composited layers. Note that fixed position elements must also create stacking contexts for this to work. #enable-compositing-for-fixed-position.

Hope this information helps.